# Validate if a text file contains identical records at specific line's number?

Tags: text-processing

my command looks like:

```
for i in *.fasta ; do
   parallel -j 10 python script.py $i > $i.out
done
```

I want to add a test condition to this loop where it only executes the `parallel python` script if there are no **identical** lines in the .fasta file

an example .fasta file below:

```
>ref2
GGTTAGGGCCGCCTGTTGGTGGGCGGGAATCAAGCAGCATTTTGGAATTCCCTACAATCC
CCAAAGTCAAGGAGTAGTAGAATCTATGCGGAAAGAATTAAAGAAAATTATAGGACAGGT
AAGAGATCAGGCTGAACATCTTAAGACAGCAGTACAAATGGC
>mut_1_2964_0
AAAAAAAAACGCCTGTTGGTGGGCGGGAATCAAGCAGGTATTTGGAATTCCCTACAATCC
CCAAAGTCAAGGAGTAGTAGAATCTATGTTGAAAGAATTAAAGAAAATTATAGGACAGGT
AAGAGATCAGGCTGAACATCTTAAGACAGCAGTACAAATGGC
```

an example .fasta file that I would like excluded because lines 2 and 4 are identical.

```
>ref2
GGTTAGGGCCGCCTGTTGGTGGGCGGGAATCAAGCAGCATTTTGGAATTCCCTACAATCC
CCAAAGTCAAGGAGTAGTAGAATCTATGCGGAAAGAATTAAAGAAAATTATAGGACAGGT
AAGAGATCAGGCTGAACATCTTAAGACAGCAGTACAAATGGC
>mut_1_2964_0
GGTTAGGGCCGCCTGTTGGTGGGCGGGAATCAAGCAGCATTTTGGAATTCCCTACAATCC
CCAAAGTCAAGGAGTAGTAGAATCTATGCGGAAAGAATTAAAGAAAATTATAGGACAGGT
AAGAGATCAGGCTGAACATCTTAAGACAGCAGTACAAATGGC
```

The input files always have 4 lines exactly, and lines 2 and 4 are always the lines to be compared.

I've been using `sort file.fasta | uniq -c` to see if there are identical lines, but I don't know how to incorporate this into my bash loop.

EDIT:

command:

```
for i in read_00.fasta ; do lines=$(awk 'NR % 4 == 2' $i | sort | uniq -c | awk '$1 > 1'); if [ -z "$lines" ]; then echo $i >> not.identical.txt; fi;
```

read_00.fasta:

```
>ref
GGTGCCCACACTAATGATGTAAAACAATTAACAGAGGCAGTGCAAAAAATAACCACAGAAAGCATAGTAATATGGGGAAAGACTCCTAAATTTAAACTGCCCATACAAAAGGAAACATGGGAAACATGGTGGACAGAGTATTGGCAAGCCACCTGGATTCCTGAGTGGGAGTTTGTTAATACCCCTCCCTTAGTGAAATTATGGTACCAGTTAGA
>mut_1_2964_0
GGTGCCCACACTAATGATGTAAAACAATTAACAGAGGCAGTGCAAAAAATAACCACAGAAAGCATAGTAATATGGGGAAAGACTCCTAAATTTAAACTGCCCATACAAAAGGAAACATGGGAAACATGGTGGACAGAGTATTGGCAAGCCACCTGGATTCCTGAGTGGGAGTTTGTTAATACCCCTCCCTTAGTGAAATTATGGTACCAGTTAGA
```

Comment: since with `NR % 4`, when it's 2nd line it will output 2 but when its 4th line it will output 0 which is 0<>2. you might wanted `NR%2==0` but in that way you are always checking on all the even lines number not only 2nd with 4th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify those specifc lines content with below awk and exit failure when lines were identical or exit success otherwise (instead of `exit`, you can do whatever you want to print/do for you);

```
awk 'NR==2{ prev=$0 } NR==4{ if(prev==$0) exit 1; else exit }' "./$yourFile"
```

or to output fileName instead when 2<sup>nd</sup> and 4<sup>th</sup> lines were differ:

```
awk 'NR==2{ prev=$0 } NR==4{ if(prev!=$0) print FILENAME; exit }' ./*.fasta
```

Using the exit-status of the first command then you can easily execute your next second command, like:

```bash
for file in ./*.fasta; do
    awk 'NR==2{ prev=$0 } NR==4{ if(prev==$0) exit 1; else exit }' "$file" &&
    { parallel -j 10 python script.py "$file" > "$file.out"; }
done
```